# How to ensure class template argument is derived from particular class Foo?

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ class template of specific baseclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012950/c-class-template-of-specific-baseclass)

```
class Base
{
...
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
...
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
...
};

class Unrelated
{
...
};
```

I want to have a class template ClassTemplate that accepts as parameter only classes Derived1 and Derived2 but not Unrelated, so I can do:

```
ClassTemplate<Derived1> object1;

ClassTemplate<Derived2> object2;
```

but I shouldn't do:

```
ClassTemplate<Unrelated> object3;
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`boost::is_base_of`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html) from Boost.TypeTraits:

```
template<class T> class ClassTemplate {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT((boost::is_base_of<Base, T>::value));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use boost static assert in combination with type traits